# Дубли в валютах (angular)

Tags: typescript, angular

Подскажите как избавиться от дублей?
[image: код]

```
public uniqueCurrencyList(listIntRate: any[]) {
        let listCurrencyObj: any[] = [];
        listCurrencyObj = listIntRate.map(item => item.Currency.LetterCode);
        let listUniqueCurrency: any[] = [];
        for (let str of listCurrencyObj) {
            var item = listUniqueCurrency.find(x => x == str);
            if (item === null || item === undefined) {
                let newObj = this.listItemsCurrencies.find(x => x.LetterCode == str);
                listUniqueCurrency.push(newObj);
            }
        }

        this.listItemsCurrencies = listUniqueCurrency;
    }



public uniqueCurrencyList(listIntRate: any[]) {
        let listCurrencyObj: any[] = listIntRate.map(item => item.Currency.LetterCode);
        let listUniqueCurrency: any[] = Array.from(new Set(listCurrencyObj));
        let result: CurrencyModel[] = [];
        this.listItemsCurrencies.find(x => x.LetterCode == listUniqueCurrency[0]);
        let listCurrency = this.listItemsCurrencies.map(x => x.LetterCode);
        for (let item of listCurrency) {
            if ((listUniqueCurrency.indexOf(item) !== -1)) {
                let curUnique: CurrencyModel = this.listItemsCurrencies.filter(x => x.LetterCode === item)[0];
                result.push(curUnique);
            }
        }
        this.listItemsCurrencies = result;
    }
```

начал вот так делать, но при след проходу он смотрит уже на фильтрованный массив - как его привести к начальному при инициализации?

Answer (score 3):

Самый простой и быстрый способ получить список уникальных элементов - это [Set()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set).

```js
const currencies = ['BTC', 'EUR', 'EUR'];
const uniqueCurrencies = Array.from(new Set(currencies)); // ['BTC', 'EUR'];
```